# A way to find out when credits were purchased in ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, online

Is there a way to tell when ArcGIS Online credits were purchased?  Our organization keeps everything behind the firewall in the Portal but one of our groups bought ArcGIS Online credits sometime in Fall/Summer 2017 (my predecessors documentation is not good).  We don't do much in there and these credits have not been touched and will not get used up before they expire.  Is there a way to find out when they were purchased so I can notify the group before they vanish in a few months?
I email our Esri account rep but no reply yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Information about Esri purchases, including ArcGIS Online Service Credits can be found inside [My Esri](https://my.esri.com/).

Previous transactions can be found in your **Order History.** Once you've logged in and selected your Organization, find the history from *Transactions* > *Order History* > *Reports*.

Note - your account needs to be associated with your org and assigned the proper permissions to see this information.

Comment: Material code 153418 is for AGOL credits in the Reports